# Column not found

Tags: sql-server

I tried below in sql server management, in a single query.

```
alter table add column amount2

update table set amount2=amount
```

I am getting column amount2 not found.

Can anyone tell me why this error?

Comment: Your alter command most likely failed. Check for errors in the alter command.

Comment: I don't think you specified the table you are adding the column to.

Answer (score 5):

That is not valid syntax (misses table name and column datatype) but in management studio use the batch separator `GO` between adding a column to an existing table and statements referencing the new column anyway.

Or alternatively you can use `EXEC` to execute it in a child batch.

SQL Server tries to compile all statements in the batch before execution and this will fail when it encounters the statement using this column.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things wrong here.

1. The correct syntax for adding a column is [MSDN - ALTER TABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

   ```
   ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD [ColumnNAME] [DataType]
   ```
2. 'Table' is a [Reserved Keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL Server, although it is possible to have a table named 'Table'. You need to include brackets when referencing it.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM [Table]
   ```

All together, you need

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ADD [Amount2] INT
GO -- See Martin's answer for reason why 'GO' is needed here

UPDATE [Table] SET [Amount2]  = [Amount]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this problem like this:

-- Alter the table and add new column "NewColumn"

ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [NewColumn] CHAR(1) NULL;

-- Set the value of NewColumn

EXEC ('UPDATE [MyTable] SET [NewColumn] = ''A'' ');